# default timeout value in db.savechanges()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any default timeout value for `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method. I'am working on an  application which uses `savchanges()` method to save my data into a database. However, this method is throwing an error message stating:

> "The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding".

Comment: ctx.Database.CommandTimeout = 120 //increase as much you need;

Answer (score 3):

This error may be due to:
    a deadlock somewhere in code and/or The query is complex and needs to be tuned.
So try to find it by considering above points. Let know if not solved

Thanks.

Comment: no the query is a simple one which inserts records to database using linq. The application is working fine in one server but failing in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specified a timeout with:

```
context.Database.CommandTimeout = 1000;
```

The default timeout is taken from the connector (I'm not sure you can change that, but hopefully, setting a greater timeout might help).

EDIT:
Also make sure you enclose your treatment within a using such as

```
using(var ctx = new Entity())
{
    ctx.Object.AddObject(a);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

When enclosing that way, you let the DbContext handle the opening and closing of the connection.

I suspect you have a connection which is still open and preventing you to open another one.